# Close DataSet's underlying connection explicitly?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using DataSet to retrieve data from the Microsoft SQL Server. Do I need to explicitly close the connection (or the underlying SqlDataAdapter automatically closes the connection)?

I always use DataReader (with *using*), but first time using DataSet -- that's why wondering about best practice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A `DataSet` is a disconnected 'view' on the database.
That is, you load the data from the database in a `DataSet` (actually, in a `DataTable`, which can be put in a `DataSet`), and you can close the Connection that you've used to populate the `DataTable` or `DataSet`.

You can continue to work with the data that is in the dataset.  It does not require an open connection to the DB.

In fact, you should close a DB-connection as soon as you don't need any DB access soon.  Connections to databases should be short-lived.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to call `Dispose()` for all ADO.NET members implemented `IDisposable`: connection, command, adapter, table, set, reader, etc:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using statement clean up unmanaged resources before the object is garbage collected. The connection, is an unmanaged resources so it should be close even if your are with a DataSet.

Comment: Am not currently using "using" with DataSet, that's exactly I was wondering? Do I need to close when dealing with DataSet? Thanks.

Comment: if you are using reader then you should have to close/dispose adapter and/or readers used to avoid exceptions. See my answer below.

Comment: Amit: As I mentioned above I already use "using" for DataReaders (which takes care of closing). My question is just for DataSets. Please read my question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for making things clear i am following conventional beginners way of interacting with db.

```
public DataSet GetData()
{
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connstr = your conn string;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    DataTable st = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {                   
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Your select query";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // your exception handling 
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }    
    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always think it is a good idea to keep track of my connections, no matter wich way I'm connecting to a database.

You said that you always use a datareader, but now you are using a data set.  I'm assuming that means you are using a `DataAdapter` to go with your `DataSet`.  If that is the case, and you are using MSSQL, then the `SqlDataAdapter` will open and close the connection for you, but like I said, I like to keep track of this myself, especially since you may use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` (even if you are using a `DataAdapter` most of the time) at some point, and the `SqlCommand` will not manage your connection state for you.

`SqlDataAdapter` doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx